# How to split a string by delimiter and put each string into a different vector?

Tags: c++, parsing, split

I'm trying to take an input which will consist of 3 substrings and parse it:

City name, latitude and longitude.

EX: `"Monticello 36.8297222 -84.8491667"`

So that I can `push_back()` the city, latitude, and longitude into their own `vector` objects.  But I can't figure out how to do that.

```
vector<string> city;
vector<float> latitude;
vector<float> longitude;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    fstream inData;
    inData.open(argv[1]);   // open the specified file for reading. 
    string line;
    if (!inData.fail())         // if the file exits and is opened successfully
    {
        while(getline(inData, line))            // read every line from the file until the end
        {
            //here is where I want to parse and pushback into it's vector
        }
    }
    inData.close();
```

Comment: Why not make a class that stores those three attributes as members and have a vector of that class type instead of 3 parallel vectors?

Comment: the delimiter is a space?

Comment: @RichardHodges yes

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm planning on switching to a struct but I thought it was be easier with 3 different vectors.

Comment: I think you will find it easier with a class/struct

Comment: `inData >> city_name >> lati >> logi;` and then copy/move them into your containers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c answers pretty much anything to do with splitting a string.

Answer (score 0):

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can take an additional parameter, a delimiter character, which is by default set to '\n'. You are in fact using it to read line by line.

What you could do, after reading in one line, is to assign that line to an instance of `std::istringstream` and let the `operator>>` split it by space (default behaviour).

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vectors(3);
while(std::getline(inData, line)){
    std::istringstream iss{line};

    std::string token;
    size_t i = 0;
    while(iss >> token){
        vectors[i++].push_back(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to split it and push it back into 1 vector. But the whole point of this question was to split the line and have each element pushbacked into it's own vector

Comment: ah, sorry. didn't get that

Comment: You might want to remove the line about using getline again, now that you have changed to using istringstream

Comment: `operator>>` reads whitespace-delimited values, so there is little difference between using `std::getline(iss, token, ' ')` and `iss >> token`

Comment: thanks guys, I forgot to remove that part after I edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stringstream (better: an istringstream) to parse the line and write the results into variables; use then the variables to pushback them into the vectors:

```
while(getline(inData, line)) 
{
  std::istringstream ss (line);

  std::string city_s;
  float longitude_f;
  float latitude_f;

  if (ss >> city_s >> latitude_f >> longitude_f) {
    city.push_back(city_s);
    latitude.push_back(latitude_f);
    longitude.push_back(longitude_f);
  }
}
```

Comment: You will probably want to check the result of `operator>>` before doing the pushes: `if (ss >> city_s >> latitude_f >> longitude_f) { city.push_back(city_s); latitude.push_back(latitude_f); longitude.push_back(longitude_f); }`

Answer (score 0):

A refactored and more complete version of the original code. Uses c++11.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

struct place {
    std::string city;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
};

std::vector<place> read_places(std::istream& is)
{
    place buffer;
    std::vector<place> places;
    while (is >> buffer.city >> buffer.latitude >> buffer.longitude) {
        places.push_back(std::move(buffer));
    }
    return places;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // preconditions
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "usage: myprog <inputfile>\n";
        std::exit(4);
    }

    std::fstream inData(argv[1]);
    if (!inData) { std::cerr << "failed to open " << argv[1]; std::exit(100); }

    auto places = read_places(inData);
    inData.close();

    // now use places
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Where which vectors contain the values? The struct? Could I just do cout << place.city << endl;?

Comment: @GeorgeWisten yes. Try it.

Comment: Didn't work, error: no member named 'city' in 'std::__1::vector<place, std::__1::allocator<place> >'
    for(int i = 0; i < places.size(); i++){cout << places.city[i] << endl;} @RichardHodges

Comment: @GeorgeWisten try `places[i].city`. places is the array, not city.

Comment: it complies, but doesn't print anything out

Comment: @GeorgeWisten time to single-step with the debugger. Is it actually reading in the values? is the file name correct? etc?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use string tokenizer - strtok() and use " " as a delimiter. Here is the link which might help you - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/